# NameError: name 're' is not defined... already imported re in the code and built in function

Tags: python-3.7

I keep getting "NameError: name 're' is not defined", even though I have already imported re in my code AND the built in function `pat_count()` defined in library_s19_week2.py.  I tried all the possible places to import re but none seemed working. Please help!

My code:

```
import re

hash_pat = re.compile(r'#\w+')
hash_counter = pat_count(hash_pat)
tweet_table['hash_count'] = tweet_table.apply(lambda row: hash_counter(row['tweet']), axis=1)
```

Traceback for the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-1880eb903ae9> in <module>()
     10 
     11 hash_pat = re.compile(r'#\w+')
---> 12 hash_counter = pat_count(hash_pat)
     13 tweet_table['hash_count'] = tweet_table.apply(lambda row: hash_counter(row['tweet']), axis=1)
     14 

/content/library_s19_week2.py in pat_count(pattern)
     95 def pat_count(pattern):
     96     import re
---> 97 
     98     pat = re.compile(pattern)
     99 

NameError: name 're' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my bug: 
`hash_pat = re.compile(r'#\w+')` should be `hash_pat = r'#\w+`.

As seen in the function `pat_count()` in the traceback, `hash_pat` is an input to `re.compile()`.